# Show convergence in C-norm implies convergence in $L_p$-norm

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I attempted to start with the $L_p$ norm and raise it to the power of $p$ but got stuck because I realized that I have no idea how to eliminate the integrand.

---

**$L_p$ norm:**
$||f||_p = ||f||_{L_p[a,b]} = (\int_{a}^{b}~|f(x)|^p~~dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

$\\$

---

**C-norm:**
[image]

Comment: I removed the tag numerical-methods. Your question is otherwise intact.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why? I'm using this in a numerical methods class

Comment: The tag for numerical methods is described here https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/numerical-methods/info 
The purpose of numerical analysis is to analyse and develop reliable, robust and efficient algorithms for computing approximate solutions to real life problems.While we frequently draw heavily on, say, real and complex analysis, linear algebra, these fields are not perceived as parts of numerical analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|f_n(t)-f(t)| \le ||f_n-f||$ for all $f,f_n \in C$ , all $n \in \mathbb N$ and all $t \in [a,b]$. Hence

$|f_n(t)-f(t)|^p \le ||f_n-f||^p$ for all $f,f_n \in C$ , all $n \in \mathbb N$ and all $t \in [a,b]$.

This gives

$ \int_a^b|f_n(t)-f(t)|^p dt \le \int_a^b ||f_n-f||^p dt =(b-a)||f_n-f||^p$.

Therefore

$||f_n-f||_p \le (b-a)^{1/p}||f_n-f||$.

Conclusion: $||f_n-f|| \to 0$ implies $||f_n-f||_p \to 0$ .

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(\int _a^b|f_n-f|^p)\le \max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^p\times (b-a)^p$

Choose $\epsilon<1$.

Now since $f_n\to f$ in $C-$ Norm

$\implies ||f_n-f||=\max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon(<1)\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$

$\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|^p<\epsilon$

$\implies \max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^p< \epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$.

Hence $||f_n-f||_p=(\int _a^b|f_n-f|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}< \epsilon (b-a)$

Comment: But I have used that only @Fred